# Horizontal scrollbar never appears in Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I'm trying to make the horizontal scrollbar appear when the table width is less that the total column widths.

I have set the width for each column, but somehow it treats the numbers like ratios. If I define 2 columns with the same width value, the columns will have 50% width.

For example,

```
columns.Bound(p => p.column1).Width(40);
columns.Bound(p => p.column2).Width(40);
```

would be rendered the same way like

```
columns.Bound(p => p.column1).Width(100);
columns.Bound(p => p.column2).Width(100);
```

So, if the columns have 20 and 30, the columns would 40% and 60% of the width respectively.

Considering that I have set the width for each column, what do I miss?

Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzfUw.png

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>

@media (max-width: 800px) 
{
.gridClassName {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
}
<style>
```

> //change the max width to a number upto where the scroll should appear